# Bind to action method

Tags: mvvmcross

Is it possible to use a simple action method - just like with Caliburn.Micro - instead of a command with MvvmCross bindings?

Example:

```
    public void Action()
    {
        Tip = 11;
    }

<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    local:MvxBind="Click Action" />
```

It doesn't work out of the box, I tested that.

While I found a lot of samples about adding new *target* bindings, I didn't find a single one about adding a new *source* binding.

**UPDATE:**
This works now out of the box with the Rio binding. To use it, add the MvvmCross MethodBinding NuGet package to the *Android* project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Up until now, much of the emphasis for MvvmCross has been on allowing multi-platform target binding with the source remaining mainly 'vanilla' `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

There have been some deviation in terms of ViewModel structure - e.g.:

- the `MvxCommandCollection` - http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/fixing-mvvm-commands-making-hot-tuna.html
- some users using Fody - http://twincoders.com/blog/codigo-limpio-con-fody/

Recently, several new feature requests have also been logged in this area:

- AutoCommands - I think this is what you are asking about here - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/301
- Rio binding sources - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/299
- Tibet binding - https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/298

Because of these, I do expect more functionality to be exposed in this area in the future...

---

With that said, if you wanted to get this working today, then MvvmCross Binding is overrideable so you could fairly easily do it:

1. Implement an `ICommand` that invokes a MethodInfo using reflection (for completeness this should probably also use a parameter if available) - some kind of `InvokeMethodCommand` (code for this left to the reader!)

.

2. Implement an `MyMethodSourceBinding` class which wraps the `InvokeMethodCommand` - something like:

```
public class MyMethodSourceBinding : MvxSourceBinding
{
    private readonly MethodInfo _methodInfo;

    protected MyMethodSourceBinding(object source, MethodInfo methodInfo)
        : base(source)
    {
        _methodInfo = _methodInfo;
    }

    public override void SetValue(object value)
    {
        // do nothing - not allowed
    }

    public override Type SourceType
    {
        get { return typeof(ICommand); }
    }

    public override bool TryGetValue(out object value)
    {
        value = new InvokeMethodCommand(source, _methodInfo);
        return true;
    }
}
```

3. Override MvvmCross's registered `IMvxSourceBindingFactory` with your own implementation that can detect when a method is present - sadly most of this is cut and paste coding today - it would be something like

```
public class MySourceBindingFactory
    : IMvxSourceBindingFactory
{
    private IMvxSourcePropertyPathParser _propertyPathParser;

    private IMvxSourcePropertyPathParser SourcePropertyPathParser
    {
        get
        {
            if (_propertyPathParser == null)
            {
                _propertyPathParser = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxSourcePropertyPathParser>();
            }
            return _propertyPathParser;
        }
    }

    public IMvxSourceBinding CreateBinding(object source, string combinedPropertyName)
    {
        var tokens = SourcePropertyPathParser.Parse(combinedPropertyName);
        return CreateBinding(source, tokens);
    }

    public IMvxSourceBinding CreateBinding(object source, IList<MvxPropertyToken> tokens)
    {
        if (tokens == null || tokens.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new MvxException("empty token list passed to CreateBinding");
        }

        var currentToken = tokens[0];
        if (tokens.Count == 1)
        {
            return CreateLeafBinding(source, currentToken);
        }
        else
        {
            var remainingTokens = tokens.Skip(1).ToList();
            return CreateChainedBinding(source, currentToken, remainingTokens);
        }
    }

    private static MvxChainedSourceBinding CreateChainedBinding(object source, MvxPropertyToken propertyToken,
                                                                    List<MvxPropertyToken> remainingTokens)
    {
        if (propertyToken is MvxIndexerPropertyToken)
        {
            return new MvxIndexerChainedSourceBinding(source, (MvxIndexerPropertyToken) propertyToken,
                                                          remainingTokens);
        }
        else if (propertyToken is MvxPropertyNamePropertyToken)
        {
            return new MvxSimpleChainedSourceBinding(source, (MvxPropertyNamePropertyToken) propertyToken,
                                                         remainingTokens);
        }

        throw new MvxException("Unexpected property chaining - seen token type {0}",
                               propertyToken.GetType().FullName);
    }

    private static IMvxSourceBinding CreateLeafBinding(object source, MvxPropertyToken propertyToken)
    {
        if (propertyToken is MvxIndexerPropertyToken)
        {
            return new MvxIndexerLeafPropertyInfoSourceBinding(source, (MvxIndexerPropertyToken) propertyToken);
        }
        else if (propertyToken is MvxPropertyNamePropertyToken)
        {
            //**************************
            // Special code is here

            var propertyToken = (MvxPropertyNamePropertyToken) propertyToken;

            if (source != null)
            {
                var method = source.GetType().GetMethod(propertyToken.PropertyName, BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
                if (method != null)
                {
                     return new MyMethodSourceBinding(source, method);
                }
            }  
            return new MvxSimpleLeafPropertyInfoSourceBinding(source,
                                                                  (MvxPropertyNamePropertyToken) propertyToken);

            // Special code ends here
            //**************************
        }
        else if (propertyToken is MvxEmptyPropertyToken)
        {
            return new MvxDirectToSourceBinding(source);
        }

        throw new MvxException("Unexpected property source - seen token type {0}", propertyToken.GetType().FullName);
    }
}
```

4. Supply this source binding factory in your own custom binding builder - e.g.:

```
public class MyAndroidBindingBuilder
    : MvxAndroidBindingBuilder
{
    protected override IMvxSourceBindingFactory CreateSourceBindingFactory()
    {
        return new MvxSourceBindingFactory();
    }
}
```

5. Supply this binding builder during your setup

```
public class Setup : MvxAndroidSetup
{
    // ....

    protected override MvxAndroidBindingBuilder CreateBindingBuilder()
    {
        return new MyAndroidBindingBuilder();
    }
}
```

---

Note: This approach is only for advanced users right now... As suggested in the first part of this question, I do expect the code in this area to change quite a lot so you might also encounter some issues maintaining a fork in this area. (Indeed the code in this area has already changed quite significantly on the Tibet Binding branch within the GitHub repo!)

Comment: Many thanks! The `MyMethodSourceBinding` I already got, but I didn't know how to register it. Thanks to your answer, I now do. Keep up the good work!

Comment: Thanks - was really excited to get a question in this area - would love to hear how you get on :) Sorry that `IMvxSourceBinding` will probably be changing underneath you because of Tibet - but I'll try to keep breaking changes to a minimum.

Comment: Don't worry about changing IMvxSourceBinding because of me, I can adapt ;-)